# Will there be an issue when this.setState is used inside of .then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

While I was working on a project, there some case that I have to change a state when user update a data.

Here is the code :

```
     state = {
        changedReservationStatus: toJS(this.props.reservationViewModel.getReservation())
    }

    reloadPageData = async () => {

        const { reservationViewModel, reservationOrderViewModel } = this.props

        const reservation = toJS(reservationViewModel.getReservation())

        await reservationViewModel.fetchReservation(reservation.id).then(changedReservationStatus => this.setState({ changedReservationStatus }))

    }
```

( **reservation** variable contains a data of an array. )

When user clicks save button, **reloadPageData function** works and then **await reservationViewModel.fetchReservation** starts to work, it triggers **this.setState** after **.then** statement.

But as you may know **reservationViewModel.fetchReservation** and **this.setState** both work asynchronously.

when I console.log **this.state.changedReservationStatus** inside **render function**, it renders the data I want to get.

But is it okay to use **this.setState** inside of **Promise**?

Will there be any issue?

Comment: *But is it okay to use this.setState inside of Promise?*, **Yes**. Its perfectly fine. *Will there be any issue?* Depends on what you do later. If you need to perform certain action after the state is updated, put a callback in setState: `this.setState( newState, postUpdateCallback)`

Comment: Thanks, I feel anxious when I have to use multiple async

Comment: Also, you used *await reservationViewModel* but also added *.then*. You can remove async await in that case since you are initiating .then() which is a promise

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly fine to use setState inside promise.then(). You might have seen that inside componentDidMount() we perform side-effects and then set the state once the API call is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution .

```
state = {
        changedReservationStatus: toJS(this.props.reservationViewModel.getReservation())
    }

    reloadPageData = async () => {

        const { reservationViewModel, reservationOrderViewModel } = this.props

        const reservation = toJS(reservationViewModel.getReservation())

        await changedReservationStatus = reservationViewModel.fetchReservation(reservation.id);
        this.setState({ changedReservationStatus });
    }
```

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the solution the OP already has? What did you change? This is just a game of spot-the-difference. It doesn't even attempt to answer the question (which is a simple yes / no question).